# Have python code execute indefinitely until a key is pressed

Tags: python, while-loop

I was trying to get a script to run indefinitively until I pressed a key (In this case 'q'). After trying multiple combinations of switching conditions and moving the code around, I couldn't figure out how to do this. Can someone help me with making the functions ('right' and 'left') loop until I press the key 'q'? Also, I want the script to continue running even if I press 'q'. This is so that I can still use the functions left and right even if I turned them off. Thanks

```
import time
import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key
import pyautogui

pykeyboard = Controller()


def right():  # This is the action I want to do
    while keyboard.read_key(.1) != "q":
        time.sleep(.2)
        pykeyboard.press('d')
        pyautogui.keyDown("space")
        time.sleep(5)
        pyautogui.keyUp("space")
        pykeyboard.release('d')


def left():
    while keyboard.read_key(.1) != "q":  # This should continue executing until 'q' is pressed
        time.sleep(.2)
        pykeyboard.press('a')
        pyautogui.keyDown("space")
        time.sleep(3)
        pyautogui.keyUp("space")
        pykeyboard.release('a')


while True:

    if keyboard.read_key() == "t":  # This listens for when 't' is pressed
        right()
    if keyboard.read_key() == "r":
        left()
    if keyboard.read_key() == "+":
        break
```

Comment: `keyboard` is not defined.  Is that supposed to be `pykeyboard`?

Comment: Why are you using three modules to do the same thing here?  Can't `keyboard` do everything you want?  It has `on_press_key` and `on_release_key` events.

Comment: I'm using different modules as of now because I want to expand my code and keyboard does not have the functions I'll need in the future.

Comment: one `while`-loop may block other loops and functions and you may have to run them in separated threads.

Comment: your loops use `sleep` so they can missed when you really press `q` - I would use separated thread to check `q` and set global variable `running = False`  and use loops with  `while running:` instead of `while keyboard.read_key(.1) != "q":`

Comment: every `read_key()` may get different value and missed when you really pressed `t`, `r` or `+`. You should use one `value = keyboard.read_key()` and later compare with `if value = "t"` `if value == "r"` `if value == "+"`

Comment: Why not `while True` instead of `while keyboard.read_key` in left/right with check for 'q' as it is done in the main while loop with '+'?

Answer (score 0):

I used multi threading (like furas sugested) to make another script that would look if the letter 'q' was pressed, which would then proceed to kill the original function.